# 3-way binding example for a more complicated workflow in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am looking into Firebase as a solution to a realtime tool I would like to build. Lets say a UI that gets a list of products from Firebase and lets customer click on items in the list to load them in an editor. Lets also say that UI shows an iframe of the same information, perhaps presented differently. When customer makes changes to the data in the editor I would like to have the iframe content bound to same resource and updated as well.

I have worked through the simple examples on your site and proof-opt-concept works fine when its only a simple object with a name value pair. However I am unclear as to how to proceed with $binding more complex objects so that they can be loaded into a form, edited and day synced back to Firebase.

For example if this is my data:

```
"products": [
       {
           "name": "Shiney Red Sparkles",
           "path": "/product",
           "images": [
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"
           ],
           "price": "129.99",
           "currency": "dollar",
           "options": [],
           "description": "These things are shiney. And red!",
           "vlnId": "0"
       },
       {
           "name": "Summer Dress",
           "path": "/product",
           "images": [
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"
           ],
           "price": "129.99",
           "currency": "dollar",
           "options": [],
           "description": "Summer dresses are nice on hot days",
           "vlnId": "2"
       },
       {
           "name": "Summer Shoes",
           "path": "/product",
           "images": [
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
               "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"
           ],
           "price": "129.99",
           "currency": "dollar",
           "options": [],
           "description": "Summer shoes are comfortable at the beach",
           "vlnId": "3"
       },
```

My proof-of-concept UI uses a repeater to generate a list with ng-click, which in turn passes / loads a directive with the object clicked on. This is where Ive run into a blank wall. The object passed through to directive isn't a $firebase object any more. Ok, i can grab the $firebase child:

```
$scope.currentProduct = $scope.products.$child(product.id);
```

This sort of works, by passing it through to the directive and using ng-change in the directive. However I run into problems unbinding the child element from the directive ...

What would be helpful is a guide to doing more advanced things with $firebase as I have wrapped it in s service so I can just inject a service object that has the ability to manage the firebase connections for me.

I a case like this, where I want to get a list of items and edit a list of items in realtime, is it better to work with one list (http://****.fb.io/products/) and bind/unbind the children to a directive or grab the list from firebase and re-grab the items data from firebase when I want to edit it as that may be easier to unbind when edition his done?

It's hard to tell from the SO posts related to 3way binding which is relevant to the current $firebase service and all the examples are pretty simple chat services that don't use more complicated objects or don't need 3way binding included in the app. Any thoughts on where to find some more info on this type of problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You should add to the topic & tag "AngularJS", which may be the source of your issue/confusion.

Comment: Thanks Tom, you are correct a directive was the culprit of the weird behavior I was seeing. That said, It would be nice to have some guidelines for dealing with more advanced real world data structures on the Firebase documentation site or in their example projects. I'm sure they have limited resources and it looks like they are working on it from a recent job posing on Hacker News.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Researching this with a colleague the weird behavior I saw in the Firebase backend was due to the way firebase objects were passed to the directive that is used to edit them. 3way binding was working correctly.

The reason I didn't post much code is that I am interested in some best practices and or lessons learned when in the early stages of prototyping one or more bi-directional apps. My use case is that these apps may look and feel different but they use the same data and the 3way binding opens up some very cool possibilities in my UI's. In researching the general guidelines I mentioned as well as the issue that lead me down the path to SO I couldn't find much on Firebase.io or the internet in general so I wondered if the SO community had anything.

Comment: A general "best practice" for any programming for me is to get a barely-working demo with no bindings or saving.  Then small add & test pieces at a time, like add hard-wired saving, then dynamic saving, etc.

Comment: @tomByrer For typical crud apps I agree. However the prototype I am playing with atm is pretty far outside of the typical edit, save, view & maybe publish content management app. This is why were are investigating the live updating with Firebase. At a high level we want to give customer access to their content and content meta data so they can change it and view the changes in real time via iframe, other tab whatever. So they work with a clone of their data, they can easily and quickly play with asset changes until they are happy and we eliminate saving and reloading from their flow.